# Do you have advantage when multiple sources give advantage and only one gives disadvantage?

Tags: dnd-5e, stacking, advantage-and-disadvantage

As I understand it:

- if you have Advantage from two different sources, you simply have Advantage (no stacking)
- if you have advantage from one source, and disadvantage from one source, they cancel out.

So what if you have advantage from two or more sources, and disadvantage from one source?  My assumption is that you simply have advantage, or put another way, you have Advantage on a roll when the number of Advantages is greater than the number of Disadvantages (and vice versa).

Is that correct?

Answer (score 62):

Having both advantage and disadvantage on your roll from *any* number of sources always means you have neither. (Even if you have a dozen sources of advantage, and just one source of disadvantage.)

From the Basic Rules section on advantage:

> If circumstances cause a roll to have both advantage and disadvantage, you are considered to have neither of them, and you roll one d20. This is true even if multiple circumstances impose disadvantage and only one grants advantage or vice versa.

Answer (score 18):

No, advantage and disadvantage cancel each other out, regardless of how many there are from any source.

> If circumstances cause a roll to have both advantage and disadvantage, you are considered to have neither of them, and you roll one d20.  **This is true even if multiple circumstances impose disadvantage and only one grants advantage or vice versa.**  In such a situation, you have neither advantage or disadvantage (PHB 173).