# Can creatures see through the darkness and fog cloud spells creatures on the other side of the AOE?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Both the darkness and fog cloud spells make everything inside a sphere heavily obscured.

According to (PHB p.183):

> A heavily obscured area—such as darkness, opaque fog, or dense
> foliage—blocks vision entirely. A creature in a heavily obscured area
> effectively suffers from the blinded condition (see appendix A).

But it has been erratad to:

> A heavily obscured area doesn’t blind you, but you are effectively
> blinded when you try to see something obscured by it.

So, does this mean that creatures are able to see clearly everything that isn't in the heavily obscured area, including on the other side of it?

I think this might illustrate what I'm trying to say better.

[image: Illustration]

Will a creature standing on the yellow dot have disadvantage on attacks against a creature standing on the red dot (since they are effectively blinded to it) but see a creature standing on the green dot clearly?

Comment: Related: "[Interaction between fog cloud and new vision errata rule](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122315)" and "[Does this errata allow vision out of an area of Darkness?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86453)" and "[Does the Darkness spell block vision?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86510)" and "[If I am attacked from an area of heavy obscurement, am I under the effects of the Blinded condition?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/131327)"

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate, it seems it has been asked and answered before.